# Start new activity for result

Tags: android, android-activity

I've encountered a issue that I can't call back from an activity. Entering form Activity 1 to Activity 2 but it can't return. Can anybody tell me where did I get wrong?
Here is my code:

Activity 1:

```
OnClickListener changeTextOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CHANGETEXT);

  }
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case CHANGETEXT:
      Bundle b = data.getExtras();
      this.Text = b.getString("Text");

    }
  }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  newText.setText(newText.getText().toString());
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    newText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  b.putString("Text", newText.getText().toString());
  intent.putExtras(b);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();

}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.shotboxv3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.shotboxv3.Setting"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: What is the value of `CHANGETEXT`?

Comment: CORRECT its a int value is 1

Comment: Are you sure that `onActivityResult()` is not being called? Have you added logging or set a breakpoint there?

Comment: I've always used just the one parameter like setResult(RESULT_OK), without the intent in there. Not sure on what the syntax difference is there.

Comment: Please post also the manifest entry for the calling activity!

Comment: I don't really. There is no response after I clicked the button. kinda wierd

Comment: Why this line `newText.setText(newText.getText().toString());`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Does the `Setting` activity get started? Also, have you checked logcat for errors? Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important/valuable

Comment: What's implementing the onClickListener in Activity 2? A new OnClickListener or the Activity?

Comment: David: Activity 1 is MainActivity and Activity2  is Setting.

Comment: Michael:  Its a new OnClickListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is the Activity that is implementing OnClickListener, in the onCreate of Activity 2, you need to set the listener of the button you're clicking to the Activity it is in:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I tried but its still not working. I am wondering do I need to add StartActivity()? I don't think StartACtivityforResult need it but.. There is no respond when I am clicking the button so it makes me wondering abt that..

Comment: Case close. You are right. I was using auto generated one and it doesn't work. Sometime Eclipse just do this to me..